# post to wall with facebook action script 3 sdk

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

I'm writing an app for Android using Adobe AIR 3.0 and facebook action script 3 sdk to enable user social experience. I can't call facebook methods using ExternalInterface, so I have to make all request using GRAPH api. 
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

So, if someone have experience working with this SDK, please provide me with code example how can I post to users wall (text + URL link + image) using:

1) app requests

2) streamPublish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function publish(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {

        var o:Object = 
        {

            attachment: 
            {
                media: [{
                    type: "image",
                    href: "http://www.example.com/",
                    src: img_path
                }],
                name: "title",
                href: "http://www.example.com/",
                caption: "test",
                description: "test",
                properties: {
                            "Link": { text: "Link", href: path},
                            "Link": { text: "Link", href: path}
                        }
                },
                action_links: 
                  [{ 
                     text: "", 
                     href: "" 
                  }]
                };

        Facebook.ui("stream.publish", o, callback, "iframe");
    }
```

Comment: Do you get stuck with such error?? 341 Feed action request limit reached

Comment: To stop spamming FB impose a max number of posts you can make through the API in a rolling 24 hour window, and you've hit that i think